# The JVM heap size does not add up

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I started a Java 8 JVM with VM param:

```
-Xms10M -Xmx10M
```

The structure of the heap is like this:

```
PSYoungGen: 2048K
   eden space: 1024K
   from space: 1024K
   to space: 1024K

ParOldGen: total: 7168K
```

My questions are:

1. Why eden+from+to is not equal to PSYoungGen? I think they both made up young generation.
2. Why PSYoungGen + OldGen = 9M? where is the other 1M heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shows the *sizes*, not the occupancy. At any given point in time, one `Survivor` spaces is *empty*, so :

```
PSYoungGen = "eden space" (1024K) + one of the two "from/to space" (1024K)
```

Both `Survivor` spaces still need space reserved, and `ParOldGen` is what is "left", which is 10M-3M (eden and two survivor spaces). I guess this is just about how you read that and how you interpret it...